# how to save file as zip without saving it to local folder

Tags: python, zip, streamlit

I'm trying to create a download function for my streamlit app. But what I currently have allows me to download a zip file via a button on my streamlit app but unfortunately it also saves it to my local folder. I don't want it to save to my local folder. The problem is when I initialize the file_zip object. I want the zip file in a specific name ideally the same name of the file that the user upload with a '.zip' extension (i.e datafile that contains the string file name as a parameter in the function). But everytime I do that it keeps saving the zip file in my local folder. Is there an alternative to this? BTW I'm trying to save list of pandas dataframe into one zip file.

```
def downloader(list_df, datafile, file_type):

    file = datafile.name.split(".")[0]
    #create zip file
    with zipfile.ZipFile("{}.zip".format(file), 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED) as file_zip:

        for i in range(len(list_df)):
       
            file_zip.writestr(file+"_group_{}".format(i)+".csv", pd.DataFrame(list_df[i]).to_csv())
           

        file_zip.close()
    
    #pass it to front end for download
    zip_name = "{}.zip".format(file)

    with open(zip_name, "rb") as f:
        bytes=f.read()
        b64 = base64.b64encode(bytes).decode()
        href = f'<a href=\"data:file/zip;base64,{b64}\" download="{zip_name}">Click Here To Download</a>'
        st.markdown(href, unsafe_allow_html=True)
```

Comment: Please update your question with some sample zip filenames with the exact location you want them saved to.

Comment: no where local .. because I created a button in my streamlit app to let users download the file. I tried using io.BytesIO to replace the given path but it doesn't write the csv file.

Comment: I think I misunderstood the question - you want to create a zip file server side than let the user download it? And you don't want it to be created in the server folder? Where do you want it? In RAM only (until download completes)? How about a /tmp folder?

Comment: Are you saying that you want to write the zip file to a different folder? Or not write it at all? When using `io.BytesIO`, what do you mean by "doesn't write the csv"? The CSV should be written to the bytesio buffer but then you have to `seek(0)` to read it again.

Comment: @LevM. Yes that's what i want to do only in RAM until it completes

Comment: @tdelaney hmm can you give example? I want it to write but not save into my local folder

Comment: You want it to write into your local folder, but not save into your local folder? That is confusing. With `io.BytesIO` the zipfile will stay in memory and will not write to storage (except maybe memory swap file).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to create the zip file in memory and use it later to build a base64 encoding. You can use an `io.BytesIO()` object with `ZipFile`, rewind it, and read the data back for base64 encoding.

```
import io

def downloader(list_df, datafile, file_type):

    file = datafile.name.split(".")[0]
    
    #create zip file
    zip_buf = io.BytesIO()
    with zipfile.ZipFile(zip_buf, 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED) as file_zip:
        for i in range(len(list_df)):
            file_zip.writestr(file+"_group_{}".format(i)+".csv", pd.DataFrame(list_df[i]).to_csv())
    zip_buf.seek(0)
    
    #pass it to front end for download
    zip_name = "{}.zip".format(file)
    b64 = base64.b64encode(zip_buf.read()).decode()
    del zip_buf
    href = f'<a href=\"data:file/zip;base64,{b64}\" download="{zip_name}">Click Here To download</a>'
    st.markdown(href, unsafe_allow_html=True)
```